# Active profile defined in app.props however Environment variable returns empty array of active profiles

Tags: java, spring-boot

The issue I am having is: active profile defined in application.properties via spring.profiles.active=development. However, when I use Spring's Environment variable to getActiveProfiles(), all that is returned is an empty String array. The application boots up with "The following profiles are active: development". Appreciate any help with this. Below is a simple class to check if I can retrieve the profile.

Already tried autowiring an Environment variable to no avail. This class is marked with @Component and implements EnvirontmentAware.

Note: I have looked at nearly every SO thread regarding this issue so please do not mark as a dupe as none solved my issue.

```
@Override
public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;

    System.out.println(environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
}
```

And of course, we get an index out of bounds exception.

application.properties (some omitted due to sensitive information)

```
spring.profiles.active=development
```

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan("uk.co.demo*")
@Configuration
public class EbecsIntegrationAdapterApplication {

@Value("${activemq.broker_url}") private String amqBrokerUrl;
@Value("${activemq.username}") private String amqUsername;
@Value("${activemq.password}") private String amqPassword;
@Value("${server.ssl.key-store}") private String amqKeystore;
@Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}") private String 
amqKeyStorePassword;


@Bean
public ConnectionFactory activemqConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
    ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new 
     ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(this.amqBrokerUrl + "? 
    jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1");
    connectionFactory.setUserName(this.amqUsername);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(this.amqPassword);
    connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
    connectionFactory.setTrustStore(this.amqKeystore);
    connectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword(this.amqKeyStorePassword);
    connectionFactory.setKeyStore(this.amqKeystore);
    connectionFactory.setKeyStorePassword(this.amqKeyStorePassword);

    return new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
}


@Bean
public ActiveMQComponent activemqComponent(JmsTransactionManager 
jmsTransactionManager, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    activeMQComponent.setTestConnectionOnStartup(true);
    activeMQComponent.setTransacted(true);
    activeMQComponent.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
    activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    activeMQComponent.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);

    return activeMQComponent;
}

@Bean
public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
}

@Bean
public SpringTransactionPolicy springTransactionPolicy(TransactionTemplate transactionManager) {
    return new SpringTransactionPolicy(transactionManager);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EbecsIntegrationAdapterApplication.class, args);
    TestEnv testEnv = new TestEnv();
    testEnv.printEnvs();
}
```

TestEnv Class:

```
@Component
public class TestEnv implements EnvironmentAware {

private Environment environment;

@Override
public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

public void printEnvs() {
    System.out.println(environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you passing -Dspring.profiles.active flag while booting up your application? And can you add your application.properties file in the question?

Comment: I am not currently passing that value. Just using spring.profiles.active. Have updated question to include properties.

Comment: on startup spring boot always shows the active profiles. **The following profiles are active...** second line. What do you see?

Comment: Hi, this is what it prints out: "The following profiles are active: development". However, the Environment.getActiveProfiles() function returns an empty String[] array.

Comment: then the component is not picked up by spring. all your components need to be in the same package or a direct child-package of your main-class

Comment: This class is in the main package of the application which also components scans the entire project.

Comment: please provide main-class. Using ```@SpringBootApplication``` already does a ```@ComponentScan```

Comment: I should also add that if I autowire an Environment variable or use EnvironmentAware interface, my Environment variable always comes through as null.

Comment: Adding main class now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `EbecsIntegrationAdapterApplication` and `TestEnv` are in the same package

- leave out unneeded annotations
  `@SpringBootApplication` is already a `@Configuration` component, does already load you application.properties and does already a `@ComponentScan`
- If you need extra packages to be scanned you should NOT add a * at the end of the package name. Best is to stick with the best practices [using-boot-structuring-your-code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EbecsIntegrationAdapterApplication {
```

- remove `new TestEnv()` in main(args)
- autowire `Environment` via constructor injection

```
@Component
public class TestEnv {

  private Environment environment;

  public TestEnv(Environment environment) {
     this.environment = environment;
     printEnvs();
  }

  public void printEnvs() {
    System.out.println(environment.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
 }

}
```

Comment: You my friend are a hero! This worked!. Is it possible to replicate where the class using the env variable in a different package?

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: So if I was to use printEnvs() in a package outside of the main package it is not possible?

Comment: in main package or all the sub-packages(child-packages). [structuring-your-code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

Comment: Hi Dirk, do you happen to know why my environment variable becomes null when I try to pass it to another class in a different package? I would presume the object would still retain its values...

Comment: as long as your class is spring managed: class needs to be a ```@Component```, a ```@Service```, a ```@Configuration``` or is created as a ```@Bean``` and is located in the main package in the sub-packages(child-packages). See my previous comment